# Error while passing a POST data to form wizard

Tags: django-forms, django-templates, django-formwizard

I have an initial form as below

**forms.py**

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
  activity_no = forms.CharField()
  username = forms.CharField()
```

**views.py**

```
def test(request):
if request.method == 'POST' :
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid() :
        act_no = form.cleaned_data['activity_no']
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        form_data = {}
        form_data['activity_no'] = act_no
        form_data['username'] = username

        return render_to_response("test1.html", { 'form_data' : form_data}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
     form = LoginForm()

return render_to_response("test.html", {'form': form }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**test.html**

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<form action="/todo/test/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**test1.html**

```
 {% extends "admin/base.html" %}

 {% block content %}

 <form action="/todo/login/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
     {% for name, data in form_data.items %}
       <input type="hidden" name={{name}} value={{data}}>
     {% endfor %}

     <input type="submit" value="Yes"/>
 </form>

 {% endblock %}
```

I fill this form, display few contents of a file and pass the above form data to a form wizard
But when I pass the data to the form wizard via post method in the template, I get a "ManagementForm Data missing" error but if the data is passed through the GET method, I don't get any error but as defined, the data is seen in the url in the GET method ( in my case it contains username which I don't want to disclose)

**My Form Wizard**

```
class LoginWizard(SessionWizardView):

def __name__(self):
    """When using decorators, Django tries to get the name of the
       function and since we're a class, we'll fail. So add this method to
       compensate."""
    return 'LoginWizard'

template_name = "wizard_form.html"
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs) :
    form_data = process_form_data(form_list)
```

My query is that how would I handle the post data in the form wizard.
Please let me know if I am missing anything or any other information is required from my end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `{{ wizard.management_form }}` in your template as explained it in reference [django wizard templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#creating-templates-for-the-forms).

Like:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<form action="/todo/test/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ wizard.management_form }}
    {{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Add that in all templates for wizard.